# BizTalk and DB2 CLOB

Tags: db2, biztalk, biztalk-2009

Has anyone had experience dealing with DB2 stored procedures which take a CLOB input parameter and calling that stored procedure from BizTalk?

I've tried changing the schema type to `string`, `base64binary`, `hexbinary`, `byte`, but no matter what I get this error:

`Error details: The parameter value for parameter 1 could not be converted to a native data type. Parameter Name: P_EML_BODY, Data Type: Long strings of input text<br> More long strings of input text <br>More long strings of input text, Value : CharForBit`

Answer (score 0):

It might be the way the parameters are being created and in what order.  Take a look [here](http://www.biztalkgurus.com/forums/p/15183/29436.aspx).  Are any of them null or empty?

Comment: All the parameters are in order and have the correct values. I output the message XML right before I send it and have verified this.